# Algorithm to randomly generate a color palette in Delphi

Tags: delphi, colors

How to beautifully generate random colors in Delphi?
I have this code in java, but I didn't manage to translate into Delphi.

```
public Color generateRandomColor(Color mix) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int red = random.nextInt(256);
    int green = random.nextInt(256);
    int blue = random.nextInt(256);

    // mix the color
    if (mix != null) {
        red = (red + mix.getRed()) / 2;
        green = (green + mix.getGreen()) / 2;
        blue = (blue + mix.getBlue()) / 2;
    }

    Color color = new Color(red, green, blue);
    return color;
}
```

Comment: Using the answer you linked you and a little bit of googling it should be pretty trivial to translate that into delphi code.

Comment: You know an algorithm already, so with little effort **you** can do this in Delphi.

Comment: What do you have started so far? We need something to at least go on. Assuming you know how to make a color, just figure out how to make a random number in delphi and you should be able to conver the java example right?

Answer (score 4):

just follow the code you posted as an example and translate it to Delphi, it is rather easy to do

```
function GenerateRandomColor(const Mix: TColor = clWhite): TColor;
var
  Red, Green, Blue: Integer;
begin
  Red := Random(256);      
  Green := Random(256);
  Blue := Random(256);

  Red := (Red + GetRValue(ColorToRGB(Mix))) div 2;      
  Green := (Green + GetGValue(ColorToRGB(Mix))) div 2;
  Blue := (Blue + GetBValue(ColorToRGB(Mix))) div 2;
  Result := RGB(Red, Green, Blue);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.Color := GenerateRandomColor;
end;

initialization
  Randomize;
```

Comment: This is not a correct translation. default should be `clWhite` (255, 255, 255), and `getRValue(red)` (etc), should be `getRValue(mix)` (etc). also, `TColor` should be transformed via `ColorToRGB`. BTW, why do you use `generateRandomColor` as a local function? plus Delphi (usually) has it's own code/naming convention.

Comment: @kobik of course you're right, there should be `getRValue(mix)`, my bad. i've edited code;
but where should  I use `ColorToRGB()`?  in `GetXValue` calls? but `getRValue(clRed)` returns `$FF` as `getBValue(clBlue)` also returns `FF`. seens everything is ok, isn't it?
Seems you're also correct about default parameter value as White, because in example image all colors are quite light. but it doesn't matter in this example.

ps: what is wrong with my local functions and naming conventions? :)

Comment: Yes, `ColorToRGB` is needed in `GetXValue`. `TColor` might be negative (system colors). I also don't think the test for (mix > 0) is needed - original Java example tests for null. I'll edit your answer to show what I mean with local fucntion/naming. You can roll it back if you don;t like it :)

Comment: @kobik it is clear about local functions :) I often use local methods when they are needed only in context of this function and I never need then in another places.
Also I don't like methods wich are not belong to class, the same with global vars, I think it is bad practrice. The only situation I use such methods is when I need to return some object instance wich I can't create directly or something like that.

yes, `mix > 0` is not needed, because result is the same. but in case when `mix=0` we do 3 extra function calls, plus and divs, so we can avoid this;

Comment: IMHO `GenerateRandomColor` is a function (not a methods), meant to be used globally by your application(s). just saying.

Comment: @kobik talking about coding styles, in this example: i never call variables starting with uppercase (the same with simple types as `integer`). I use 4 space idents; I always use `()` in method calls; and I like "stairs" coding style, thats why it was red, blue, green instead of r,g,b sequence :) and yep, I never use button1Clicks and form1, especially in code examples ;)

Comment: I follow Delphi sources coding conventions. You might have your own flavor.  It's your answer. you can edit or roll-back my edit ;)

Comment: @kobik if you need global function, then create `TColorTools` record/class with `class function generateRandomColor()` method :)

Comment: That's also a fine idea.